# it is possible to use parentheses in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm newbie to solr and I wonder if it is possible to use parentheses like this:
if I want to search for `field1:val1 NOT field2:val2 NOT field3:val3`, can I do : `field1:val1 NOT (field2:val2 AND field3:val3)`.
I see that in the [doc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Grouping) there is something similar but it doesn't exactly what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes*, lucene queries do allow the use of parentheses in queries, and the syntax you've provided is perfectly valid.

However, *No*, those two queries will not get the same results. This isn't some Lucene quirk, though, those two queries are not logically equivalent. According to [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Text_searching): NOT a AND NOT b = NOT (a OR b)

`field1:val1 NOT field2:val2 NOT field3:val3` is equivalent to `field1:val1 NOT (field2:val2 OR field3:val3)`.  These would return results containing "val1", but neither of "val2" or "val3"

`field1:val1 NOT (field2:val2 AND field3:val3)` would return results that have "val1", and *not both of* "val2" and "val3". Results could have either of them present, just not both.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-` to achieve that.

e.g

```
/select?q=field1:val1&fq=-field2:val2&fq=-field3:val3
```

you can add as many filter queries(fq) as you want .

So basically `q` will return all the docs that have `field with value val1` and then the filter query(fq) will filter out the results so that the only docs that will return are which do not have field2 with value val2 and `field3` with value `val3`